# jquery reveal popup pass id

Tags: jquery, popup

how to pass id using jquery popup reveal?

for simple pass id < a href=".php?id=21" >

but in reveal

```
    <a href="test.php?id=121"  data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="fade"></a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
            <?php include 'test.php'; ?>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

how i want to get the id that i`m pass to test.php ,sorry if my english not so good

Comment: Why do you want to pass the `id`? You want to use it as parameter for your `test.php` when it loads the contents?

Comment: yeah...i want to do like show profile info depend on id.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

on your test.php

$id = print_r(id);

then echo $id